# Effectively use a library included with CocoaPods

Tags: afnetworking, cocoapods, afoauth2manager

This is my first attempt with CocoaPods. So far so good, I've been able to include a library create the first workspace with the library that I needed. This is my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'SDK-auth' do
  pod 'AFOAuth2Manager', '~> 2.2'
end
```

Now I'm trying to use the `AFOAuth2Manager` lib inside my project and here is my question... what I've to do to include it? Currently I'm writing something like

```
@import AFOAuth2Manager;
```

but I receive this error: `Could not build module AFOAuth2Manager`

Is this the right way to include the module? or am I doing anything wrong?